# Correct way to display data from Rest Api in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have have a service in Angular, which calls data from an API. So when I am trying to display the data it is not displaying?

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {

   api: string = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=gb&category=entertainment&apiKey=8ee8c21b20d24b37856fc3ab1e22a1e5';

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) { }

getAll(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.api)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      console.log(error.error.message)

    } else {
      console.log(error.status)
    }
    return throwError(
      console.log('Something is wrong!'));
  };
}
```

**Component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  public data = [];
  public noData: any;
  public results = [];

  constructor(
  private api: ApiService 
  ){ }

  getAll() {
    this.api.getAll().subscribe((results) =>  {
      this.data = results.results;
      console.log('JSON Response = ', JSON.stringify(results));
    })
  }

 ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

**JSON response structure**

```
{ 
   "status":"ok",
   "totalResults":70,
   "articles":[ 
      { 
         "source":{ 
            "id":null,
            "name":"Thesun.co.uk"
         },
         "author":"Mary Gallagher",
         "title":"Holly Willoughby breaks down in tears on This Morning as she meets disabled boy who speaks against all odds - The Sun",
         "description":"",

etc etc
```

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let news of data">
   <h3>{{news.json}}</h3>
</div>
```

Where Am I going wrong?

Comment: Show `console.log('JSON Response = ', results);` output

Comment: Nothing in console.

Comment: JSON data structure added

Comment: @Sole I think you want that `articles` list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`articles` is a property of data, so you have to loop `data.articles`

Try like this:

```
<ng-container *ngFor = "let news  of data?.articles">
  <h3>{{news.title}}</h3>
</ng-container>
```

Another option:

TS:

```
this.data = results.articles;  // here now you have list of all articles
```

HTML:

```
*ngFor="let news of data"
```

**[`Working Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8hw2hu?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: Maybe it is something to do with the JSON structure I am trying to get and it is not correct how I am calling?

Comment: Check the modified answer

Comment: @AdritaSharma I think it should `results.articles`?

Comment: In the question he has stored in data propeerty: `this.data = results.results;`

Comment: @PrashantPimpale is correct, if you look at the real api response, it should be `results.articles` @AdritaSharma

Comment: Yesss... I see it now. Thanks @PrashantPimpale, c_ogoo

Answer (score 7):

When you ask for a "correct" way, it is commonly recommended to avoid subscriptions in component when you don't have to. Prefer `async`pipe instead.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public data$: Observable<Data[]>;

  constructor(
    private api: ApiService 
  ){ }

 ngOnInit() {
    this.data$ = this.api.getAll();
  }
}

<ng-container *ngIf="data$ | async as data; else pending">
  <div *ngFor="let article of data.articels">
     <h3>{{news.json}}</h3>
  </div>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #pending>
  <div>pending</div>
</ng-container>
```

Advantage: You never forget to unsubscribe, you have easy control over pending state

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are assigning object response, not array. So try to assign array:

```
this.data = results.results.articles;
```

OR add `articles` to iterate through array of articles:

```
<div *ngFor="let news of data?.articles">
   <h3>{{news.json}}</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check once

```
<div *ngFor="let news of data.articles">
   <h3>{{news.author}}</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**With this JSON response:**

```
{ 
   "status":"ok",
   "totalResults":70,
   "articles":[ 
      { 
         "source":{ 
            "id":null,
            "name":"Thesun.co.uk"
         },
         "author":"Mary Gallagher",
         "title":"Holly Willoughby breaks down in tears on This Morning as she meets disabled boy who speaks against all odds - The Sun",
         "description":"",
```

**Your component should be:**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  public data = [];
  public noData: any;
  public results = [];

  constructor(
  private api: ApiService 
  ){ }

  getAll() {
    this.api.getAll().subscribe((results) =>  {
      this.data = results.articles;
    })
  }

 ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

**Your template:**

```html
<div *ngFor="let news of data">
   <h3>{{news.json}}</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: it does not work.